# Приложение вылетает при нажатии на кнопку.

Tags: android

По нажатию кнопки **`Hello World`** приложение вылетает.

---

```
package helloworld.ndsys.pro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {

    CheckBox ChkBox;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ChkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    }

    public void onOkClick(View v) {
        if (ChkBox.isChecked()) {
            ChkBox.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            ChkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    public void onCanClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
        android:text="OK"
        android:onClick="onOKclick"
        android:layout_width="100dp">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:onClick="onCanClick"
        android:layout_width="100dp">
    </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто **`Java`** чувствительна к регистру и ошибка вызывалась тем, что в **`Layout`** файле `android:onClick` имело значение *`onOKclick`*, а в Activity файле обработчик был именован как *`onO`**`kC`**`lick`*.

Comment: Это java чувствительна